# How to mention users when they connect to a specific voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

My discord bot is supposed to create voice channels and get information about users (in order to mention them later) in these channels. The order of actions is that the user connects to specific channel, and then bot creates a new channel and moves user to it. After that, the user uses !invite, then the bot sends message with mention of user who created this channel. Also bot edits it with mention of just connected user.

The problem is that I need to get another user id immediately when he connected to `created_channel`.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@client.command(name='invite')
async def invite(ctx: commands.context):
    poster = discord.Embed(colour = 0xFF5500)
    poster.add_field(name = ctx.message.content[7:],
    value = f'''{new_connected1.mention}
    {new_connected2.mention}
    {new_connected3.mention}
    {new_connected4.mention}
    {new_connected5.mention}'''
    )
    await ctx.send(embed = poster)

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update( member, before, after ):
    if after.channel.id == 1019214989829079060: #channel where I connect to create another channel
        for guild in client.guilds:
            category_contains_created_channel = discord.utils.get( guild.categories, id = 1019215017150787604) #category where I want to place new channel
            created_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(name = f"{member.display_name}'s", category = category_contains_created_channel, user_limit = 5) #creating channel
            await created_channel.set_permissions(member, connect = True, mute_members = True, move_members = True) #setting perimissions
            await member.move_to(created_channel) #moving member to new channel

            def check(x, y, z):
                return len(created_channel.members) == 0 #checking members in the channel
            await client.wait_for('voice_state_update', check = check)
            await created_channel.delete() #deleting channel if none is in the channel
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll achieve the monitoring of voice_channels for activity and acting on it by using a combination of bot.event (or client.event) and tasks loop (@tasks.loop).
You may find the basic idea of background tasks here: [Python: Making a Discord bot (Part 9: Background Task)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RK8RzuUMYt8)

By using a background task you can start it after the creation of the Voice Channel, and stop after the deletion.

Working code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import asyncio

intent = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '*', intents = intent)

created_channels = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(0)

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel and after.channel.id == [channel_id_here]: #channel_id where user connects to receive a voice_channel
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            category_contains_created_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id = [category_id_here]) #category where you want to place new channel
            created_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(name = f"{member.display_name}'s", category = category_contains_created_channel, user_limit = 5) #creating channel

            await created_channel.set_permissions(member, connect = True, mute_members = True, move_members = True) #set permissions for member on newly created channel
            
            created_channels[created_channel.id] = created_channel.jump_url #update dict to contain newly created channel's join url for invite later, could be updated with channel's member list for updating your embed.

            await member.move_to(created_channel) #move member to new channel
            await asyncio.sleep(5) #sleep 5 seconds due to moving delay
            await check.start(member, created_channel) #start background task, passing member and created channel as arguments
    else: #if the event was not triggered by moving to requests channel
        return

@tasks.loop(seconds = 30) #loop every 30 seconds
async def check(member, channel):
    if not channel.members: #if no members in voice_channel
        await asyncio.sleep(15) #allowing time for next check
        if not channel.members:
            await channel.delete() #deleting channel if none is in the channel
            check.cancel() #terminate background task
            

bot.run('<<-TOKEN_GOES_HERE->>')
```